# Powershell - Where-Clause multiple JSON Array key

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I cannot find any solution why my where-clause in my powershell do not give me the output I would expect.

I have a JSON File looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "server1",
    "tag": ["App", "Mid-Tier", "User"],
    "domain": "domainname",
    "alias": ["Alias3"],
    "ip": null,
    "tcp": 8080,
    "active": false,
    "apps": ["ARS", "Tomcat"],
    "patch": null,
    "hotfix": null
  },
  {
    "name": "server2",
    "tag": ["Reporting"],
    "domain": "domainname",
    "alias": ["Alias3"],
    "ip": null,
    "tcp": 8080,
    "active": false,
    "apps": ["ARS", "Tomcat"],
    "patch": null,
    "hotfix": null
  },
  {
    "name": "server3",
    "tag": ["DB"],
    "domain": "domainname",
    "alias": ["Alias1", "Alias2", "Alias3", "Alias4"],
    "ip": null,
    "tcp": 8080,
    "active": true,
    "apps": ["SQL"],
    "patch": null,
    "hotfix": null
  },
      {
    "name": "server5",
    "tag": ["Reporting"],
    "domain": "domainname",
    "alias": ["Alias1"],
    "ip": null,
    "tcp": 8080,
    "active": false,
    "apps": ["ARS", "Tomcat"],
    "patch": null,
    "hotfix": null
  }
]
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**
Ok I have to give you more details what I am trying to accomplish/understand:

I have 3 Files:
- a JSON File with data like above
- a script storing all functions and variables
- a main script

This is how my function looks like:

```
function opl_GetHostList {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [parameter (
        mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage = "Enter alias name.")]
        [string[]]
        $Aliasname,
    [parameter (
        mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage = "Enter tag name.")]
        [string[]]
        $Tagname,
    [parameter (
        mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage = "Enter app name.")]
        [string[]]
        $Appname,
    [parameter (
        mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage = "Enter Active State: Either false or true. Default = true")]
        [bool]
        $Active = $true,
        [parameter (
        mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage = "Choose selection Object.")]
        [string[]]
        $Select
)


$WhereArray = @()

# evaluate these with contains comparison
if ($Aliasname) {$WhereArray += '$Aliasname -contains $_.alias'}
#if ($Tagname) {$WhereArray += '$Tagname -contains $_.tag'}
#if ($Appname) {$WhereArray += '$Appname -contains $_.apps'}

# Build the where array into a string by joining each statement with -and
$WhereString = $WhereArray -Join " -and "
# Create the scriptblock with your final string            
$WhereBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($WhereString)

$opl_Hostlist | Where-Object {($WhereBlock.invoke()) -and $Active -eq $_.active} | Select-Object $Select
```

}

so now comes the part I don't understand.
If I use following in the main.ps1:

```
$opl_Hostlist | Where-Object {$_.alias -contains "alias3"} | Select-Object name
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name
----
server1
server2
server3
```

BUT, if I use it with my function:

```
opl_GetHostList -Aliasname alias3 -Select name
```

I get this **OUTPUT:**

```
name
----
server1
server2
```

So why do I not get the "server3" with my second method when I am calling the data with my function?

Very thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSON you have posted, you will get `ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid array passed in, extra trailing ','. (1018)` error. This is because of the unwanted comma after the last item.

And I would suggest to use `-in` instead of `-match` operation as `Alias` property is a `list`. In your comparison, left operand is a single element and right operand is a list, hence you have to use `-in`, otherwise `-contains`.

```
if ($Aliasname) {
    $Aliasname | ForEach-Object{ $WhereArray += "$_ -in `$_.alias"}
}
$WhereArray -Join '-or'
```

Comment: Yeah, that typo came from this post. But your suggestion using '-contains' doesnt change anything

Comment: I was not able to repro this, the code works for me. What version of PowerShell are you using ?

Comment: Since you have posted your function here, I realize that the usage of `-contains` is making problem here. You have to use `-in` and the reason is updated in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem then is that, if I have more than just one parameter like `-Aliasname alias2, alias3` I dont get any output at all.

Comment: I would suggest you to put `-or` and build `WhereString` for each alias, there is no operator to do this.

Comment: I tried, but that didn't do it eather: 
`if ($Aliasname) {
        $WhereArray = ($Aliasname | foreach-object {'$Aliasname -in $_.alias'}) -Join " -or "
        $FinalString += "($WhereArray)"
    }`
Maybe I am doing it wrong. Strange is it does always works with one given parameter, never with two :/

Comment: Use this,
`if ($Aliasname) {
    $Aliasname|ForEach-Object{ $WhereArray += "$_ -in `$_.alias"}
}` and then do `-join` with `-or` before any `-and` operation.

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work as well: getting an error. :/ well, so much thank you for trying helping me, getting tired for not getting the result I want, somehow I am sure it is just something small.

Comment: There is a correction in the above comment, `$_.alias` was not properly escaped. it will be
`if ($Aliasname) { $Aliasname|ForEach-Object{ $WhereArray += "$_ -in \`$_.alias"} }`

Comment: Still error... however, this is what the function should build together when it would work: `$opl_Hostlist | Where-Object {("alias2" -in $_.alias -or "alias3" -in $_.alias) -and $true -eq $_.active} | Select-Object name, alias, tag` 
I just cant get my function to do that together. One point you where right and gave me the correct answer is about the operatior `-in` which in the manually created string works fine.